# when the are 2 receiver sharing single queue, how to balance the work at receiver side

Tags: rabbitmq

If, I have question about to balance the workload on my 2 application servers (rabbitmq client). It connects to same Rabbit queue. If, the producer publish new message to queue in sequencial. How can I manage the application server to get new message by rotating 1,2,1,2....

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ facilitates this automatically by using `round-robin`:

> By default, RabbitMQ will send each message to the next consumer, in sequence. On average every consumer will get the same number of messages. This way of distributing messages is called round-robin.

you can find more information on it here: https://live.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-objectivec.html, and go to the header `Round-robin dispatching`.